# MySQL Error "Duplicate entry ' ' for key " while inserting the data in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

My model classes i have:

> LetterDoc.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "letter_doc")
public class LetterDoc implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    TwoP twoP;


    private String docFile;

    //i ommited getters and setters
    public LetterDoc() {

    }
```

> Document.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long docId;

    private String docName;

    @Transient
    private boolean checked=false;

    public Document() {

    }
```

> TwoP.java

```
@Embeddable
public class TwoP implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "letterNo",unique=true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Letter letter;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentId",unique=true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Document document;

    public TwoP(Letter letter, Document document) {

        this.letter = letter;
        this.document = document;
    }

    public TwoP() {

    }


}
```

The json data that i coming in my api send from client side is:

[image]

In my api i have used this method to consume the json data:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/letter/create", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public SLDto postAllOne(@RequestBody SLDto sldto) {

Letter letter = letterRepository.save(new Letter(clkLetter, sldto.getLetterDto().getInOut(),
                sldto.getLetterDto().getInOutNo(), sldto.getLetterDto().getInOutDate(),
                sldto.getLetterDto().getLetterIssuedSubBy(), sldto.getLetterDto().getLetterFile(),
                sldto.getLetterDto().getRepresentativeName(), selection, assessment));
    //Please consider letter is inserted with Id no 22.

            for (DocumentDto documentDto : sldto.getDocumentDto()) {
                TwoP twoP = null;
                LetterDoc letterDoc = null;

                System.out.println("loopedonce");
                Document document = null;
                System.out.println("total documents Id is" + documentDto.getDocId());
                document = documentRepository.findById((long) documentDto.getDocId()).get();
                System.out.println("Document Id from db is" + document.getDocId());
                twoP = new TwoP(letter, document);
                letterDoc = new LetterDoc();
                letterDoc.setTwoP(twoP);
                letterDoc.setDocFile(null);
                letterDocRepository.save(letterDoc);
                     } 
}
```

SlDto.java class

```
private LetterDto letterDto;
    private List<DocumentDto> documentDto;
    private List<SelectionCustomOfficeDto> selectionCustomOfficeDto;
```

Now in the **For Loop** i used above,it must be looped twice as the number of Json data coming is Two.Yes it is looping twice and in this line `document = documentRepository.findById((long) documentDto.getDocId()).get();` ,I am getting Document object twice but when inserting it in **letterDocRepository.save(letterDoc);** ,it shows me

> Duplicate entry '22' for key 'UK_5pahc9x5lwh5k4owpm3vjfq3c'

'22' is recent ID created when i inserted in "letter" table

Since my **documentDto.getDocId()** returns me the 1,2 coming from JSON data and though they are different but the program is showing me error.

To see also what is happening I debugged them to see whether the data is arriving from database as:

[image]

Error is :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '22' for key 'UK_5pahc9x5lwh5k4owpm3vjfq3c'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
```

Comment: There are probably 100+ questions on Stack Overflow covering that stack trace/error.  Please edit your question and show only the 10-20 relevant lines of code.

Comment: i saw the realted errors but i didnot found the solution :(

Comment: Use annotation EmbeddedId TwoP twoP instead of Id in your LetterDoc class

Comment: no it is still showing me same error after changing to EmebeddedId

Comment: Cannot see all the relevant sources, where is Letter.java? Also, the use of "@Embeddable" as an "@Id" should be done through the use of "@EmbeddedId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is from `Cascade` property behavior, with `Persist` it will try to insert it when you save `letterDoc` object.
try to use `cascade.MERGE` instead.

if you want to have Persist, don't insert any association you declared with `cascade.persist` as Hibernate will do that for you.

Comment: did you try both possibilities?